# Least amount of people such that two are neither friends nor have any common friends

Tags: combinatorics

In a group of $m$ people each person is friends with exactly $n$ other persons, $m \gt n$. $k$ people are arbitarily chosen. What is the lowest possible value of $k$ such that we can be completely sure that at least two of the $k$ persons are neither friends nor have any common friends?

Comment: Have you got any thoughts to share? You will get a lot more responses if you tell us what you have tried already :)

Comment: Working out the details for $k=1,2$ might suggest a general approach.